# Why my google map is not showing?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i have tried almost everything but i am unable to correct my code.My code is not showing google map and markers on it. I have a sqlite3 db canberra.db from where i am getting the data.

**canberra.db:**

```
 CREATE TABLE `markers` (
  `city_id` INTEGER,
   `name`   TEXT,
   `latitude`   TEXT,
   `longitude`  TEXT,
   `type`   TEXT
   )
```

Any help would be highly appreciated thanks in advance.

**test.php:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <style>
          #map {
          height: 400px;
         width: 100%;
          }
       </style>
      </head>
      <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
     <div id="map"></div>

    <?php
      class MyDB extends SQLite3
      {
       function __construct()
     {
       $this->open('canberra.db');
  }
  }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db){
     echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
   echo "Opened database successfully\n";
     }

  $sql=<<<EOF
      SELECT * from markers;
   EOF;
     $result = $db->query($sql);

     $json = array();
     while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){


       echo $json[]['lat'] = $row['latitude'];
       echo $json[]['lon'] = $row['longitude'];
       echo $json[]['name'] = $row['name'];
        echo $json[]['type'] = $row['type'];



      }

$db->close();


      echo "Operation done successfully\n";


     ?>



    <script type="text/javascript"> 
     function initMap() {
    var locationsJSON = '<?php echo json_encode($json) ?>';
     var locations = JSON.parse(locationsJSON);

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     zoom: 2,
     center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     });
    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    console.log(locations[i]);
      var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon);
       bounds.extend(myLatLng);
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
    }


   }
  </script>
  <script async defer
       src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDooxT39owZBkpRXCGKPbRuQd5fSkr0Xvk&callback=initMap">
       </script>
```

Comment: any javascript errors in the console?  What does `console.log(locations[i]);` give you?

Comment: Why locations[i][1], locations[i][2]? Didn't you call your properties lat, lon and name?

Comment: console.log is giving me nothing :( @duncan

Comment: What does `console.log(locationsJSON)` give you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map is not showing the markers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913025/google-map-is-not-showing-the-markers)

Answer (score 1):

Try var_dumping your $json array and you'll see what's wrong.

You can replace your while loop content with:

```
  $json[] = array(
     'lat' => $row['latitude'],
     'lon' => $row['longitude'],
     'name' => $row['name']
  );
```

Comment: my while is correct the problem is that map is not showing :(

Comment: With your actual code, you're creating 3 rows for each lat/lng combination in you're while loop so accessing it the way you do it in your javascript won't work.

Comment: i have tried your method but nothing showing :( help me please

Comment: what's the output of your echo json_encode($json) ?

Comment: when i echo the json_encode($json) right after while loop it gives me :Opened database successfully -35.2811262149.1309785Mrwei'sRestaurant-35.341291149.052956Baitong Laos & Thai CuisineRestaurant[{"lat":"-35.2811262"},{"lon":"149.1309785"},{"name":"Mrwei's"},{"lat":"-35.341291"},{"lon":"149.052956"},{"name":"Baitong Laos & Thai Cuisine"}]Operation done successfully  .................................but it is not displying the echo of initMap()

Comment: above comment is the result of this : while($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC) ){
   
  echo $json[]['lat'] = $row['latitude'];
       echo $json[]['lon'] = $row['longitude'];
       echo $json[]['name'] = $row['name'];
        
                 
   
 
   }
    echo json_encode($json);
    
    $db->close();

Comment: Seeing your comment, you didn't use the code I provided you, you can see that you JSON isn't well formatted. You're a beginner so go easy: start by doing a code snippet with no PHP: set your JSON object containing the locations manually. When you get that example working, try generating the same JSON using PHP. Then at the end, use your real data. Your code contains a lot of mistakes so you should first learn to debug. Use var_dump when coding PHP. Use the console when coding Javascript and you'll see what's wrong. Good luck !

Comment: but i have to submit it tomorrow :( :'(

Answer (score 1):

I have change this function and my code works :)

```
    function initMap() {

  debugger;
    var locationsJSON = <?php echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;

     var locations = locationsJSON;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var marker, i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

    console.log(locations[i]);
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
}


   }
```

And one thing i also post php script at the top.

```
<?php
  class MyDB extends SQLite3


 ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

   </html>
```

i hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You create your array with

```
echo $json[]['lat'] = $row['latitude'];
echo $json[]['lon'] = $row['longitude'];
echo $json[]['name'] = $row['name'];
```

But then you're referring to the coordinates with:

```
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);
```

Change that to:

```
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i].lat, locations[i].lon);
```

Comment: i have change the code in updated section but it is still not working :(